# Using polybase and Azure blob storage to point to particular location

Tags: sql-server, azure, hadoop, polybase

I have an azure storage account with 2 blob containers
tmmdevstorage - storage account
customerfiles - blob container1
customerfileszip - blob container2

I have these set up to store identical data both zipped and not zipped in these to test for performance purposes.

my issue is getting my external tables to point to the locations, maybe someone here can further explain how this works for me. 
my create external table statement looks like this:

WITH (DATA_SOURCE = [AzureStorage],LOCATION = N'/',FILE_FORMAT = [TextFileFormat],REJECT_TYPE = 
   VALUE,REJECT_VALUE = 0)

this takes me to the root folder I believe, and it does return the expected records. 
If I wanted to specify one of my blob containers how would this look:

```
WITH (DATA_SOURCE = [AzureStorage],LOCATION = N'/customerfileszip/',FILE_FORMAT = [TextFileFormat],REJECT_TYPE = 
VALUE,REJECT_VALUE = 0)
```

This returns no records

Comment: Zip or GZip? Polybase only supports the latter

Comment: It is gzip.  I think that the files are compressed correctly, I am using the AZURE blob storage destination task in SSIS and setting it to use gzip.  I think my issue is access the gzipped files from the create external table statement.

Comment: can you include the full code like the external file format definitions ?